# Call onclick method while parsing a web page

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Disclaimer: This is my first attempt at web scraping. Do not mind if its a very simple question.

I get the html source from a web site as below.

```
def get_soup(site):
"""get the html source for a web site"""
try:
    logging.debug("Getting data from:" + site)
    req = urllib2.Request(site)
    req.add_header('Accept', '*/*')
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'web-scraping')
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()        
    return BeautifulSoup(page)       
except:
    logging.debug("Check the site: " + str(site))
    raise
```

And the soup has an onclick method as below. Is there any way to call this method while making the url request(preferably) or afterwards(if at all its possible)?

```
soup = get_soup(opt_site.replace("<symbol>", symbol).replace("<expiry>", expiry.strftime("%d%b%Y")))
spot_price = soup.findAll('table')[0].findChildren('td')[1].findChildren('span')[0]

<span>As on Dec 23, 2013 15:30:25 IST<a> <img src="/live_market/resources/images/refressbtn.gif" onclick="refresh();" style="cursor: pointer" title="refresh" /></a></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup does not handle javascript. You should use something that can handle javascript; for instance, [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).